# Using Iteration to Decode a Message in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

So I am kind-of stuck on this problem for homework. Though that's nothing new, I felt fine using just loops, but adding iteration into the mix is throwing me off. Anyway, what I would like help with is decoding a message in MATLAB. There are two different types of messages: one that involves a bunch of characters, and one that involves spaces(so an actual sentence). If I have a string of characters, I have to find every nth character, if it's a string of characters, I have to find every nth character.

```
function[code]= decodeStr(str, index)
    code = [];  %// Starts me off with an empty vector to populate
    word_in_message = strsplit(str, ' ');  %// Splits up my vector
    word_in_message = char(word_in_message); %//Turns it into a character, which I need
    find_spaces = find(str == ' '); %// Finds spaces, how I know it's not a character string
    words = (find_spaces + 1); %//Index es the word, but not too sure I need this
    Counter = 1; %// I plan to use this in the character string

    while index <= length(str)
        if find_spaces > 0 %// If it is a string with words, they'll be spaces
            code = word_in_message(index, :); %// This works in the command window. 
            code = [str(index)];
        end
        index = index + 1 ;
    end

end
```

As you can see, I am sadly lost. I know I can use words_in_message(index, :) in the command window to get the full word, but it errors out in the function. It'll complain about exceeding the dimensions and while I can see why that happens (the index = index + 1 being the culprit), I am unsure of what to do to fix it. I just keep getting it to feed back the whole string to me, which is not what I wanted. Any suggestions?

```
TestCases
 str = ['I want to go  to the   track meet and eat a Jimmy Johns ''gourmet sandwich ...
 on the first with    Wednesday Adams.'];
 [out1] = decodeStr(str,4)
      => out1 = 'go meet Jimmy on Wednesday'
[out2] = decodeStr('www.harttoregerill.com/op',3)
          => out2 = 'waterloo'
```

Sorry if this seems a bit vague. My carpal tunnel is flaring up, so I'm trying to avoid typing a lot :/

Comment: I'm not adding anything to your question, but FWIW, you don't need to be apologetic or say that you're stuck with your homework.  I've noticed that with all of the questions you have posted. This site is designed to specifically seek answers to questions that you don't know how to solve :)

Comment: Yeah but I feel bad having to come for help all the time. I feel like I should be able to do more of these than I do.

Comment: well the philosophy behind StackOverflow is "expert answers to your questions". All of us... Perhaps myself too... Have years of experience where you've only begun. It's quicker to ask someone for help than to learn on your own sometimes :)

Comment: Yeah, but it's easy to trick yourself into thinking you're actually learning when you're asking someone else for help. Though, to be fair, I wait until I've worked on these problems for ~4 hours each before asking for help. I usually work on them throughout the week.

Comment: Well, at least you try before you ask help.  It can't be said for a lot of other people here.  Ah well, good luck!

Comment: Thanks! There's no point in taking this class, if I'm not going to actually work to learn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function code = decodeStr(str, index)
    if find(str == ' ', 1)
        words = strsplit(str, ' '); 
        code = strjoin(words(index : index : end));
    else
        code = str(index : index : end);
    end;
end
```